# Need help creating a script that automatically inputs the month and day to google sheets using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having issues creating a script that will automatically input the Month on the first row and then the days of the month on the second row, for a full month or a full year.

Something that will look like this -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7vnf.png

Comment: any feedback on the proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

You do nit need a script

A1 : `2022`

A2 : `=arrayformula(if(day(A3:3)=1,A3:3,))`

A3 : `=(sequence(1,date(A1,12,31)-date(A1-1,12,31),date(A1,1,1),1))`

then put format on rows 2 and 3 as needed

[image]